# Decision after first round of peer review

Tags: publications, peer-review

I submitted an article, after the first round of peer review, i received a letter from the editor saying "Your paper should become acceptable for publication pending suitable minor revision and modification of the article in light of the appended reviewer comments". What does this means, after submitting the revision, will it still be sent for another round of peer review or the editor will handle it himself? Just curious since the revision is not much and straight to the point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are possible. Sometimes editors handle minor revisions themselves, sometimes manuscripts are sent for a quick (hopefully) review to (some of) the reviewers.